# How can I invoke Scale as a Unity Launcher item?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Unity display a Launcher icon for Spread Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33852/can-unity-display-a-launcher-icon-for-spread-mode)

The Unity Launcher has an item to invoke Compiz's Expo (Workspace Switcher). How can I do the same with Compiz's Scale?