# Expose-like spread mode in unity 2d without compiz

Tags: 11.04, unity-2d

I'm using ubuntu 11.04 with unity-2d but without compiz because my computer has a two-screen setup. 
I'd like to know if there's any way of having a view of all active applications running like Mac OS X' Expose feature. [Super+w doesn't work on unity-2d, which is a recognized bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/757312).
I've noticed some related topics (for example : [Can Unity display a Launcher icon for Spread Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33852/can-unity-display-a-launcher-icon-for-spread-mode)) but all are based on compiz and therefore are not relevant for me.
Does anyone has a clue on how to do this whithout compiz?
Thanks for your help

Edern

Comment: when i was searching for some stuff i found this blog http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/05/23/expose-type-behaviour-in-openbox/ . It is about application that provides expose like behaviour in openbox, maybe it can do same in ubuntu. Try it if you want to

Answer (score 1):

The program that does this has been a plugin for Compiz for some time. I have not seen this replicated in any other porgram, though i've seen similar in KWin (for KDE; don't use if you are on Gnome/Unity)

Answer (score 1):

I had searched this functionality for xfce but everytime I crash back to `compiz`. This functionality is given by `scale` plugin in compiz. Basically `skippy` is something not related to window managers as @Denwerko link points out but its long dead project. So for now its either `compiz` or `KWin` so you may try compiz as unity-2d itself will be using [compiz](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/uds-o-news-unity-2d-will-switch-from.html)

[Here](https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+question/142689) is how you use compiz with unity-2d

[This](https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+question/155727) may also interest you.

Comment: Thanks for all these information. I will try this but don't know if it will work since (as I mentionned before) Compiz cannot run because of my dual screen setup.

Comment: After some more searching I found http://cairo-compmgr.tuxfamily.org/ to have a plugin called mosaic which does somewhat like expose and the better thing is it can be run on top of our window manager but seems the application is still in its infancy and only keyboard shortcut can be set. You can give it a try.