# How do I create a launcher item to show all open applications?

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Unity display a Launcher icon for Spread Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33852/can-unity-display-a-launcher-icon-for-spread-mode)

I need to build a Unity launcher item to activate Compiz Scale. How do I do that?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/33852/23555

Answer (score 0):

U can replicate Super+W using Ubuntu Tweak.. This method doesn't give u a Launcher Item but its something easier, this is how its done.

1. Download it from here and Install it http://ubuntu-tweak.com/
2. Run it, Go to the Tweaks Tab.

   [image]
3. Go to Compiz Settings. Do what's shown in the image to customize Ur workspace edges.

   [image]
4. Everytime u touch the bottom right corner all ur active windows are displayed and u can switch among them easily.