# Can I change the "Workspace switcher" behavior to be "Window Spread"?

Tags: unity, launcher, workspaces

I only use one workspace, but I don't know how to reduce it to one.

That being said, I would like to know how I can change the "Workspace Switcher" behavior. I'd like to see the same thing as I see when I press Super+ W, when I click on it.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of the *Workspace switcher* launcher is hardcorded into Unity and you can't change it unless you try modifying the source of Unity.

If you want, you can create a new launcher item that lets you use Windows spread by following the answer in this question.

- [Can Unity display a Launcher icon for Spread Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33852/can-unity-display-a-launcher-icon-for-spread-mode)

---

And, you can try changing the number of workspaces by following this question:

- [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)